# orcad pspice simulation

Tags: simulation, led-driver, pspice, orcad

I am trying to simulate this OrCAD PSpice simulation based on TLD5045EJ (led driver IC) which I have downloaded from Infineon website. They already provided a test setup file for simulation, I have set the simulation profile for bias point calculation. The output was in femtoampere value even though there are two led connected in series with SW pin. I’ve attached the circuit below. What am I doing wrong? Are there similar difficulties for others in simulating this model? How to rectify this problem? The link to the simulation model and datasheet is given below.

Model: https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/lighting-ics/litix-automotive-led-driver-ic/litix-power/tld5045ej/#!?fileId=5546d4626df6ee62016e11ea702a319b

Datasheet: https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/lighting-ics/litix-automotive-led-driver-ic/litix-power/tld5045ej/#!?fileId=5546d462696dbf120169a0bb18626e7a

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The operating point is calculated at time t=0, and if your source is (what lookslto be a) pulsed source, then the initial value is zero, therefore every other node dependent on the source will have (machine precision) zero V or A. Since the model is sxplicitely steated to be for a transient analysis, then you can't rely on the operating point values, and you need to see the graphs as they evolve in time.